# Can't able to check two date values are equal or not in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
var d1 = new Date("02/22/2018");
var d2 = new Date("02/22/2018");
if(d1 == d2){

}
```

** - this is not working. its always return false. but if I write a condition 
   as bellow then its working fine.**

```
if(d1 <= d2 && d1 >= d2){

       }
```

Comment: You're comparing two different object refrences, they are never the same. Use `var d1 = new Date("02/22/2018").getTime()` to get comparable values to the date variables.

Comment: But d1 <= d2 working fine. Then why I need to write .gettime() for checking ==

Answer (score 0):

Dates are objects, and are compared by reference, bot by value. Try this:

```
d1.getTime() === d2.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be checking the reference. Can you try

```
var d1 = new Date("02/22/2018");
var d2 = new Date("02/22/2018");
if(d1.getTime() === d2.getTime()){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getTime();` method to compare two date objects.

```js
var d1 = new Date("02/22/2018");
var d2 = new Date("02/22/2018");

console.log(d1.getTime() == d2.getTime())

console.log(d1.valueOf() == d2.valueOf())
```

The `getTime()` method returns the date as an integer, what you are doing there is comparing objects, rather than value. 
 
Instead of `getTime()` you can also use `valueOf()`.
The [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method returns the primitive value of the specified object

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

```
var d1 = new Date("02/22/2018");
var d2 = new Date("02/22/2018");
if (d1.getTime() === d2.getTime()) {
    console.log("same");
} else {
    console.log("differ");
}
```